# Cannot route audio to HDMI on Pi 4 Bullseye

Tags: pi-4, audio, hdmi, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

Running latest update of Bullseye (11.1) on Pi 4 with 2 gig. Fresh fully updated copy of the OS. The menu bar audio item, which should list options, only lists "AV Jack" as an option. The VLC media player "audio_device" menu only shows "built-in audio analog stereo" as an option. Have tried suggested modifications to /boot/config.txt.

Nope. Thing is, it worked yesterday before I upgraded bullseye from 11.0

Thanks for help -- Rich

Comment: by `fresh` - do you mean you used an imager to create a fresh image on the sd card? or, did you apt upgrade from 11.0->11.1 - what is the output of `tvservice -s`

Comment: I did a download using my mac on a fresh sd card using the Raspberry Pi imager. The output just now from tvservice -s was: "tvservice is not supported when using the vc4-kms-v3d driver.
Similar features are available with standard linux tools
such as modetest from libdrm-tests."